# Not getting the input from Form in child to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I am not getting the Input from form in child to parent.**
*Having a Form in child calling it from parent*
*Having on submit editData Function.*
*On submit , it should print me the input data, but it is printing undefined*

**parent**

```
  const Main = () => {
       
        const todoData = [
            
            {id:0,todoname:"Study",todotoday:"Completing CSS today"},
            {id:1,todoname:"Coding",todotoday:"Leetcode 2 Problems"}
        ];
    
    const [onEdit,setonEdit] = useState([]);
     const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);
     


     const editData = (id,ehe,ela) =>{
       console.log(id);
     console.log("-->"+ehe);
     
     setmyArray(myArray.map(obj =>{

    if(obj.id === id){
      return {...obj,todoname:ehe,todotoday : ela}
    }else{
      return obj;
    }  
   }));
  }
  return(
   {
         myArray.map((obj)=>{
          return ( 
              <div className="todocont" key={obj.id}>
            <div className="todobox"  style={{opacity: checkedItems.includes(obj.id) ? 0.2 : '', }}>
            <h2 className="head" >Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
             <TodoIcon  />
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="editInput">
            <SetEdit className="editComp" onSubmit={() => editData(obj.id)}/>
            </div>
            </div>
            )
        })
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  
  }
```

**Child**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SetEdit.css';

const SetEdit = (props) => {

    const [fh,setfh] = useState("");
    const [El,setEl] = useState("");

    const handleHead=(e)=>{
        setfh(e.target.value);
        console.log(fh);
     }
 
     const handleElab = (e) =>{
         setEl(e.target.value);
     }

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onSubmit(fh,El);
    }

  return (
    <div  className='editInp'>
    <form  className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" placeholder='New Head' value={fh} onChange={handleHead}/>
      <input type="text" placeholder='New Todo' value={El} onChange={handleElab}/>
      <button className='btn'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SetEdit
```

*Please help me with the problem*
*---------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------*

Comment: You are not using the props anywhere, how do you know the value is not being passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your input params in callback func that you're passing to `SetEdit` component in parent.
Try this:

**Parent:**

```
<SetEdit 
  className="editComp" 
  onSubmit={(input1, input2) => editData(obj.id, input1, input2)}
/>
```

**Update:** For your question on having initial value in case of having no inputs, you can set default values for your arguments in `editData` function like this:

```js
const editData = (id, ehe = '', ela = '') => {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: what to do,to set the initial value if no input?

Answer (score 1):

Because in `<SetEdit className="editComp" onSubmit={() => editData(obj.id)}/>` you only pass the first parameter of the `editData` function and doesn't specify the `ehe` and `ela` of `const editData = (id,ehe,ela) =>{}`.

You should write it this way:

```js
<SetEdit className="editComp" onSubmit={(ehe, ela) => editData(obj.id, ehe, ela)}/>
```

Comment: what to do,to set the initial value if no input?